# how to let input not move when zooming screen

Tags: html, css

I have a background image with `width : 100%` and some inputs on it, here is an example:

[image]

Everything works good at this time, but when I want to resize my website the inputs change their direction to <<< and background stay in middle here is an example of it:

[image]

The way that I want it's when the visitor has a small screen or bigger or he want to zoom screen the inputs stay in their places and   they get smaller when zooming to 25% , I hope someone could understand me , and help me I'm stuck.

Comment: Sounds like something we can help fix...  but we would need to see your code.   Try posting it here...  or even better, creating a JSFiddle (www.jsfiddle.net) with your code so we can help.

Comment: Free hand in Paint ftw

Comment: at least website url. anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with percentage  positioning? For example

```
.box{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
width:400px;
height:400px;
margin-top:-200px;
margin-left:-200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give background-position: center center

.box {
   background-image: url(image-path);
   background-position: center center
}